# running external python program from another program

Tags: python

I have a python program **gold.py** located at **/home/laxmi/Desktop/gold/gold.py** in ubuntu.
I have a python program test.py as
**test.py**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("python", "Desktop/gold/gold.py")
```

I want this program to call  the gold.py program and display the result from gold.py

**error**

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 660, in __init__
raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
```

Comment: Please show us the actual error.

Comment: It was not there initially :/

Comment: For simple commands I like to use `os.system('python your_program.py')` as it's usage is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `TypeError`. Since you're not passing keyword arguments, the second parameter is taken to be the buffer size, which must be an integer.

Change:

```
subprocess.Popen("python", "Desktop/gold/gold.py")
```

To:

```
subprocess.Popen("python Desktop/gold/gold.py")
```

Here's the documentation for [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).  The first parameter, the only required one is `args`:

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single
>   string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args
>   if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is
>   platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable
>   arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless
>   otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

NB:

> If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or
>   else the string must simply name the program to be executed without
>   specifying any arguments.

So, if this needs to be done, you would do:

```
subprocess.Popen("python Desktop/gold/gold.py", shell = True)
```

Please read about the security risks intrinsic to this in the link provided.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya That's because you're passing the wrong pathname.  I assure you that this works.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Make sure the path is exactly what you think it is.  I just went in and tried it to make sure I'm not missing something, and it works fine.

Comment: how to give path name in args in ubuntu?

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Go into terminal, find the folder containing your file and type `pwd` for (print working directory).  Add the filename to that...I assume it will look something like: `~/Desktop/gold/gold.py`, if not try: `/home/USERNAME/Desktop/gold/gold.py`, where `USERNAME` is replaced by your username.

Comment: @ Steve neither of those is working. it says No such file or directory. further i am working in virtual environment, is this the problem?

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Did you navigate to the directory and use `pwd` to get the directory path and append the filename?  Or simply right click on the file and get its path? Again, this definitely works.  This is **no longer a python question**...

Comment: @ steve I solved the error . I need to add shell=True when I passed the string argument. add this in the answer and I will accept it

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Edited...weird, though, because it worked fine for me without it.  Maybe it's because I'm currently on Windows and not linux.  Glad you figured it out.